# Google spreadsheets: How to get average session per user instead of all users?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-analytics, google-sheets-timestamp, google-chart-api

In google spreadsheets I'm trying to get the average session per user from Google Analytics, so I tried `ga:avgSessionDuration` on metrics, `ga:date` in dimensions, it returned me the time in seconds, so I used `=TEXT(P2/86400;CHOOSE(MATCH(P2;{0\60\3600};1);"s ""s""";"m ""m"" s ""s""";"[h] ""h"" m ""m"" s ""s"""))` to transform the value into hours, minutes and seconds, like this `1 h 49 m 29 s`, but this is getting the full time session of all users.
Is there any way to get the average session PER user?

EDIT?
Tried to divide the session duration by the number of users as suggested:

Session duration

```
  =TEXT(P2/86400/duracaosessao!E16;CHOOSE(MATCH(P2;{0\60\3600};1);"s ""s""";"m ""m"" s ""s""";"[h] ""h"" m ""m"" s ""s"""))
```

Time on page

```
 =TEXT(Q2/duracaosessao!E16/86400;CHOOSE(MATCH(Q2;{0\60\3600};1);"s ""s""";"m ""m"" s ""s""";"[h] ""h"" m ""m"" s ""s"""))
```

But for both I'm getting the same result: `0 h 1 m 26 s`

Comment: `=TEXT(P2/86400;"[h]\h mm\m ss\s")` What's in P2? Average session or full session time? Can't you just divide the number by the number of users?

Comment: P2 is session duration. How do I do that?

Comment: And, What's the expected result?